# Ruby on Rails app; Admin Section not working online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I have recently deployed my Ruby on Rails app from running it locally on my machine to a VPS server. The Administration section isn't working, with username and password. It works locally, but online, I can't get in to administer my user details. The rest of the app seems to be working ok, just not the Admin.

In my db/seeds.rb I have:

```
Admin.create(:email => "admin@admin.com", :password => "admin_password")

#unless Rails.env.production?
#  1000.times do
#    Factory.create(:user)
#  end
#end

categories_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'categories.txt')
if File.exists?(categories_file)
  File.open(categories_file, 'r') do |f|
    while category = f.gets
      Category.create(:name => category)
    end
  end
end
```

Is there something I need to do to get it working correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seeded the data or added the admin to the DB. If yes, are you using devise and do you require confirmation. If this fails compare the logs on your local with those on production.

Comment: How do you mean you deployed it with the same username and password? What are you using for authentication?

Comment: Hi. No expert on Rails - took over this from someone else. I know Devise is used for users to log in/ sign up in the app. In controllers in Admin folder I can see 'class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController layout 'admin/application' end', so that probably means Admin is with Devise too. Not sure what you mean by 'seeded the data'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone ran:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:seed
```

from the production instance (whatever that is) on the server, and now it's working.